# Why is documentation the "castor oil" of programming?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

I found an unusual use of "castor oil" in this sentence, which seems to be a [common maxim](https://www.google.com/search?q="Documentation+is+the+castor+oil+of+programming"):

> Documentation is the castor oil of programming.

What is the role of *castor oil* in this sentence? Is there a story behind using "castor oil" or the usage of any type of oil is possible in this sentence?

Comment: It's actually made clearer by including the next line of the maxim - _Managers think it is good for programmers and programmers love to hate it!_

Comment: Because it's so hard to swallow.   (BTW, I never heard the phrase in about 45 years of programming.)

Comment: It's a metaphor. And @rajah9 has described it very nicely. If you want more, consider that marketing is the snake oil, and user interface design is the lubricating oil.

Comment: So nothing to do with both triggering an instant gag reflex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Health benefits

Both castor oil and documentation have many salubrious benefits.

See this [Castor Oil Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_oil); it is used:

- to help skin and hair
- as an additive
- as a laxative

With computers, documentation is used:

- to help users understand the program or application
- to clarify the workings of the program in the programmer's mind
- to explain the workings of the program in the understanding of newer team members
- to communicate to support staff the proper operation of the program or application

### Punishment

Although it has health benefits, it is distasteful to many.

I was surprised to see that castor oil has been used as a punishment, especially by Mussolini's regime (*op. cit.*). It has been used by parents to punish children, at least according to the Looney Tunes that I watched as a child. The Wikipedia article confirms:

> "Some parents punished children with a dose of castor oil."
>
> "A heavy dose of castor oil could be used as a humiliating punishment for adults, especially political dissenters."

These lyrics from "The Perfect Nanny" describe an agreeable nanny:

> Never be cross or cruel
>
> Never give us castor oil or gruel

Source: [genius.com](https://genius.com/Walt-disney-records-the-perfect-nanny-lyrics)

In that spirit, perhaps documentation could be seen as a punishment for programmers. Documentation may seen as a punishment because:

- It can be difficult for technical folk to express ideas in cogent, grammatical English.
- Documentation can be anathema to technical folk, for whom expressing concepts for a naive reader can be problematic. (In contrast, some *live* to express algorithms to a machine.)
- It requires the use of word processors (such as MS Word, which does not understand the subjunctive mood (one of its venial sins (don't get me started))).
- It requires editors, reviews, approvals, and often posting to a Version Control System.
- It has deadlines.

#### tl;dr

While castor oil and documentation are good for you, they will leave a bad taste in your mouth.

Comment: I Thank everyone, so "castor oil" has the meaning of "a necessary evil"

Comment: @M.Abdelhafid, I wouldn't say "necessary" or "evil". Just something that's good for you but unpleasant.

Comment: @ThePhoton - But that's pretty much what a "necessary evil" is. According to [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-necessary-evil), it's _something bad or unpleasant that you have to accept in order to achieve what you want_. Also, to M.A.: Yes, the phrase is being used in that way (roughly), however, it's a bit of a dated phrase, as the product is nowhere near as ubiquitous as it was, say, a half a century ago. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+castor+oil&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Comment: @J.R., "necessary" is stronger than good for you, and "evil" is stronger than unpleasant.

Comment: @ThePhoton - It's a fixed expression; you're not supposed to parse it word-by-word. See, e.g., [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/a-necessary-evil?q=necessary+evil), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/necessary-evil), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/necessary_evil), etc.

Comment: @J.R., I agree the "evil" part in "necessary evil" isn't meant literally, but usually the "necessary" part is meant pretty close to literally.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Yup, and I think _Documentation is a necessary evil in programming_ isn't a bad paraphrase of the "castor oil" version. [These bloggers](https://www.google.com/search?q="Documentation+is+a+necessary+evil") seem to agree.